# How can I make a new line in my _vimrc after using the normal i command?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, gvim

I'm very new to Vim and I have some ASCII art in my `_vimrc`.

I've inserted it there using `normal i`, but it doesn't display properly, because the `normal i` commands don't have a line break at the end. I've tried `<esc>`, but it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how I can break the ASCII art into multiple lines?

Here's my `_vimrc`:

```
" Packages
packadd! nord

" Visual settings
syntax on
colorscheme nord
language en_gb
set guifont=consolas:h11

" Functionality settings
set tabstop=4
set laststatus=2
set nu!
set guicursor=i:block-cursor
set guioptions-=T
set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=L

" ASCII art
normal i  __     __  __
normal i /  |   /  |/  |
normal i $$ |   $$ |$$/  _____  ____
normal i $$ |   $$ |/  |/     \/    \
normal i $$  \ /$$/ $$ |$$$$$$ $$$$  |
normal i  $$  /$$/  $$ |$$ | $$ | $$ |
normal i   $$ $$/   $$ |$$ | $$ | $$ |
normal i    $$$/    $$ |$$ | $$ | $$ |
normal i     $/     $$/ $$/  $$/  $$/
```

By the way I'm on Windows and I'm using GUI Vim 8.2.

Edit 1: I know, that there might be a better way to do this, but I'd like to stick to my way for now.

**MY SOLUTION:**

Edit 2: I solved it by adding `normal o` between every line of the ASCII art like this:

```
normal i $$ |   $$ |$$/  _____  ____
normal o
normal i $$ |   $$ |/  |/     \/    \
normal o
normal i $$  \ /$$/ $$ |$$$$$$ $$$$  |
```

It's **not** the best solution, but it does the job for me.

Edit 3: I might've deleted the edit summary inserted by someone else and I'm sorry. I tried putting it back, but it always disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a literal newline (displayed as `^M`). You can type this character into your `_vimrc` by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and typing <kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>m</kbd>, and then releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. So for each line you would have:

```
normal i  __     __  __^M
normal i /  |   /  |/  |^M
" etc...
```

where `^M` is not the characters "^M" literally, but the result of typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> (holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> until after typing <kbd>m</kbd>).

Comment: Cool! It works! But is there any other way of doing this, that isn't Vim-specific?

Comment: Nevermind, I got. I just had to insert `normal o` in between every `normal i` line.

Comment: @bld you should checkout `:h append()` and `:h line()`. Then you could do it in actual VimL instead of emulating keypresses.

Comment: Might be better to `:put =join(my_list_of_lines, '\n')`

Comment: @bld I really like the `normal o` one! Please post that as an answer!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've already achieved what I've wanted. @filbranden I will post it. (-:

Comment: UPDATE: I posted the `normal o` solution as an edit to my post, i think it makes more sense, than answering my own question.